# How to remove multiple markers from the Leaflet Map and add new ones?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I was trying to make a leaflet map, that gets latitude and longitude data of points and draw them onto the map, then refreshes them.

I am working with Leaflet 1.5.1 and so far I have tried creating a layer, putting the markers inside the layer and cleaning the layer when refreshing the markers.

```js
var map;
var markers = [];
var live_data = [];
var markersLayer = new L.LayerGroup(); // NOTE: Layer is created here!
var updateMap = function(data) {
    console.log('Refreshing Map...');
    markersLayer.clearLayers();
    for (var i = 0; i < live_data.length; i++) {
        var heading = live_data[i][3];
        var latitude = live_data[i][1];
        var longtitude = live_data[i][2];
        var aircraft_id = live_data[i][0];
        var popup = L.popup()
            .setLatLng([latitude, longtitude])
            .setContent(aircraft_id);
        marker = L.marker([latitude, longtitude], {clickable: true}).bindPopup(popup, {showOnMouseOver:true});
        markersLayer.addLayer(marker);
    }
}

function GetData() {
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'GET', 
        url         : 'www.filesource.com/file.txt'
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        var lines = data.split('\n'); //Split the file into lines
        $.each(lines, function(index, value) { //for each line
            if(value.indexOf(':') > 0) { //Go if the line has data in it.
                var line_data = value.split(':');
                var data_marker = [line_data[0], line_data[5], line_data[6], line_data[45]];
                live_data.push(data_marker);
            }
        });
        updateMap();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    map = L.map('LiveMap', {
      'center': [39.50157442645549, 35.190536499023445],
      'zoom': 6,
      'layers': [
        L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        })
      ]
    });
    markersLayer.addTo(map);
    GetData();
    setInterval(GetData, 60000); //every minute
});
```

The code works fine at first, creates all the markers. However, when data refreshes, more markers are being added without clearing the previous markers. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you correctly clear your previous Layers / Markers, you still keep your previous `live_data` intact since you only push new data into it and never flush it. Therefore the next call to updateMap will re-create those previous Markers...

Simply set `live_data = []` at the beginning of the callback of your GetData request.

Comment: That worked perfectly fine! Thank you very much! :)